# Did the writers of Stargate SG1 forget about the Beta gate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

When the Russians discovered their Stargate had the writer's forgotten about the BETA GATE from season 2 episode 14 that was found, recovered, stored, sealed and locked away after it was recovered from the National Intelligence Dept.?

Comment: iirc the "Russian gate" is the original one from the SGC and got blown up by Anubis. The other gate which iirc is the Antarctic one is the current gate in use

Answer (score 16):

**No, at any point in history there are only ever one or two stargates on Earth.**

From pre-history there is one gate in Antartica, [emplaced by the Ancients](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Gate), which we'll call Gate 1. At some point they ascended and the gate fell out of use. The Goa'uld arrived millions of years later and [emplaced their own gate](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Alpha_Gate) which we'll call Gate 2.

The SGC discovered Gate 2 in the 1940s and placed it in Cheyenne Mountain. This is the stargate that is used by the SCG in *SG1: Children of the Gods*. They discovered Gate 1 at the end of Season 1 (*SG1: Solitudes*) and placed it into storage at Area 51.

The Stargate Programme used Gate 2 **until it was beamed out of the SGC in Season 3, Episode 22 (*SG1: Nemesis*) and briefly used before it crashed into the ocean. The Russians recovered it and began their own covert programme.** The SGC unpacked Gate 1 and used that until it was destroyed in Season 6 (*SG1: Redemption*) at which point they started using Gate 2 again, having first leased and then bought it from the Russians, whose abortive Stargate programme had sinc been shelved.

---

To answer your specific question, the Russians didn't *discover* a Stargate, they recovered the SGC's original Stargate after it fell into the ocean in *SG1: Nemesis*, held onto it for a few seasons (and incompetently used it), then demanded various considerations to return it to its righful owners.

Comment: I wouldn't say Gate 2 was "stolen" in Nemesis. SG1 used it to evacuate from Thor's ship and it crashed together with the ship. (The NIS stole Gate 1 from storage at some point, but that's unrelated)

Comment: @CodesInChaos - After the crash it was "covertly recovered" by the Russians. Theft by finding is still theft, although you could certainly argue that it was neither the legitimate possession of the Americans or that it fell under the heading of salvage.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - But you're not wrong. It wasn't stolen from the SGC, it was stolen from the salvage site.

Comment: By international salvage law the gate was owned by the Russians. It met the conditions, the salvaged item was in "real peril" being stuck at the bottom of the ocean. Recovering it was fully voluntary at their own risk and there was no preexisting contract to perform the salvage. The Russians own it fair and square. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_salvage?wprov=sfla1 the us might demand that they give it back and accept a reward equal to it's value, but then a fairly public international court needs to assign a fair value to it which neither wanted.

Comment: @JohnMeacham - You are incorrect. Salvage law certainly would not apply to a military vessel under the control of the US government at the time of its sinking - "*Maritime experts told the Tribune they could find no regulation in international law governing the salvage procedure of a warship in international waters during peacetime*" - Note that *"title to property is not lost by sinking"* if the owner has the capacity to recover the items lost; https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/216912172.pdf

Comment: @JohnMeacham - Note Article 14 of the *[Convention for the Unification of Certain Rules of Law Respecting Assistance and Salvage at Sea](http://www.admiraltylawguide.com/conven/salvage1910.html)* ***"This Convention does not apply to ships of war or to Government ships appropriated exclusively to a public service."***

Comment: If the convention doesn't apply then it falls back to finders keepers or international diplomacy. All the Russians need to do is point out "project azorian" where the united states attempted to salvage a USSR nuclear submarine with no intention of returning it to the USSR. The united states could try to take the gate back by force or attempt to argue under international salvage law it belongs to them with a very shaky case. There wasn't really any other option to make russia return it to them.

Comment: @JohnMeacham - There's a reasonable body of opinion that salvaging a military vessel without permission is an act of war. Either way "stealing" seems an appropriate term. I suppose you could substitute "illegally salvaged" if you wanted to get all picky like

Comment: Is it relevant that it was salvaged not from a US millitary vessel but from an Asgard millitary vessel? At no point did the SGC/US Government assume de jure control of the ship during the crash. It's definitely possible the SGC just weren't able to get the actual owner of the salvage to get involved or confirm they were acting on his behalf, before having had to work out the deals with the russians anyway as a necessity.

Comment: @mattihase - It's quite a fun little thought experiment, akin to the question of who owns the Roadster in space. The short answer is that there's no real body of law dealing with extraterrestrial salvage.

Comment: @Valorum amusingly, one I imagine we'll be getting an answer to within the next decade or so as kessler syndrome becomes more and more of a problem to avoid.